# Kotlin Coroutines Job hierarchy explanation

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

While reading an interesting [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/exceptions-in-coroutines-ce8da1ec060c) on Exception in Coroutines. I came across section that includes the following image:

[image: Coroutine Job Hierarchy]

I am trying to understand how and where did the parent `Job` come from?

Although they explain it the article as:

> a new coroutine always gets assigned a new Job()

But looking at the code, I see a top level scope with a `Job`, when calling the "parent" `launch` we override it with a `SupervisorJob` and then two child `launch` which i guess inherit the parent job or create their own.

So, my question is where did the parent job came from (the one wrapping the 2 child jobs)?

Comment: I still don't understand it after 3 and a half years!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you pass to `launch` becomes the parent of the job that `launch` internally creates. That job is always of the same type, which is `StandaloneCoroutine`. You cannot control the `Job` instance corresponding to the coroutine, you can only decide on its parent.

In your diagram, the `Job()` inside the `scope` is completely ignored. The top-level `launch` creates its own `StandaloneCoroutine` and assigns the `SupervisorJob` you passed in as its parent.

In the particular situation represented in your diagram, `SupervisorJob` has no effect as it doesn't prevent any coroutine failure from spreading. The top-level `launch` will get cancelled if any of the two inner `launch` coroutines fail. The only difference will be that the `SupervisorJob` will remain active, but it will have no children at that point.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, the `SupervisorJob` in that case just replaced the `Job` of the scope?

Comment: Yes, that's what happens.